# Redux странный синтаксис

Tags: ecmascript-6, redux

Недавно в redux видел генераторы экшенов со странным js синтаксисом, не могу найти и понять что это

```
{type: ACTION_ADD, id}
```

Обтяните почему тут id без пары, это же обект. Такие примеры есть в оф документации по redux. Спасибо

Answer (score 7):

Добро пожаловать в удивительный мир ECMAScript 6 (и 7).

Это новая синтаксическая конструкция называется [*Property Shorthand*](http://es6-features.org/#PropertyShorthand) и призвана упростить фарширование объекта значениями из пачки переменных.

Если перевести этот синтаксический сахар на привычный ECMAScript 5, получится следующее:

```
{type: ACTION_ADD, id: id}
```

то есть предполагается, что ранее объявлена переменная `id`.

Comment: 3й год уже она новая :)